# differential equation using matrix exponential not consistent solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification, dynamical-systems, matrix-exponential, discrete-time

For the differential equation (physical friction)

$\ddot x=-a\cdot \dot x$

The solution can be easily found using exponential ansatz and is

$x(t)=c_1+c_2 \exp(-a\cdot t)$

Or expressing this using *initial conditions* $x_0:= x(0)=c_1+c_2 $, $v_0:=\dot x(0)=-a c_2$ it can be written as
$x(t)=1\cdot x_0+\left(\frac 1 a - \frac  {\exp(-at)} a  \right)  {v_0 }  $, $v(t)={\exp(-at)}\cdot  {v_0 }  $  .

Putting into matrix form it is:

$ \begin{pmatrix}
x(t) \\
\dot x(t)
\end{pmatrix} 
=
 \begin{pmatrix}
1 & \frac  {1-\exp(-at)} a \\
0 & \exp(-at)
\end{pmatrix}  
\begin{pmatrix}
x(0) \\
\dot x(0)
\end{pmatrix} 
$

Now however when we use matrix exponential the solution differs!
The upper solution seems more reasonable since for vanishing speed we get the position back.

$\mathbf{\dot x} =  \begin{pmatrix}
\dot x \\
\ddot x
\end{pmatrix} 
=
 \begin{pmatrix}
0& 1\\
0 & -a
\end{pmatrix}  
\begin{pmatrix}
x \\
\dot x
\end{pmatrix} 
=A \mathbf{x}
$

It should be $ \mathbf{x}=\exp(At)  \mathbf{x_0}$, so that both solutions could be compared using $
\exp(At)  = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & \exp(t)\\
1 & \exp(-at)
\end{bmatrix}  $ but they do **not coincide**.

[Matrix exponential calculation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=exp%28%7B%7B0%2C1%7D%2C%7B0%2C-a%7D%7Dt%29)

What/where is the issue/error/misunderstanding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exponential matrix is incorrect. Observe that

$$(s I - A)^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix} s & -1 \\ 0 & s + a\end{bmatrix}^{-1} = \frac{1}{s(s+a)} \begin{bmatrix} s + a & 1\\ 0 & s\end{bmatrix}.$$

Simplifying,

$$(s I - A)^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{1}{s} & \frac{1/a}{s} + \frac{-1/a}{s+a} \\ 0 & \frac{1}{s + a}\end{bmatrix}.$$

Computing the inverse Laplace we find,

$$\exp(A t) = \mathcal{L}^{-1}\{ (s I - A)^{-1} \} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & \frac{1}{a} - \frac{1}{a}\exp(-a t) \\ 0 & \exp(-a t) \end{bmatrix}$$

which is consistent with your ansatz solution. Check how you computed your exponential matrix. It looks like you did a term-by-term exponential, which is almost never correct (only works for diagonal matrices).

Comment: Did you use Neuman inversion of geometric series or how does that work with Laplacian, could you elaborate?  L(exp(At))=[sI-A]^(-1)

Comment: That's the Laplace transform (and its associated inverse operation). The term by term Laplace transform of $\exp(A t)$ is $(s I - A)^{-1}.$

Comment: Is it a more robust or easier method to calculate matrix exponential? Btw I used WolframAlpha as linked in the question, is my input wrong?

Comment: You'll want to use [this command](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=expm%28%7B%7B0%2C1%7D%2C%7B0%2C-a%7D%7Dt%29) instead; it is (expm) not (exp).

Comment: Good to know, it was only the wrong input.  One has to watch out with the commands,  also for [MatrixLog](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%28MatrixLog%7B%7B1%2Ct%7D%2C%7B0%2C1%7D%7D%29%2Ft).

Comment: Also it is useful to check using differentiation (Lie theory) to get the *generator* matrix [d/dt exp At at t=0 is A](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Divide%5Bd%2Cdt%5D+%5C%2891%29%7B%7Bcos%5C%2840%29t%5C%2841%29%2Csin%5C%2840%29t%5C%2841%29%7D%2C%7B-sin%5C%2840%29t%5C%2841%29%2Ccos%5C%2840%29t%5C%2841%29%7D%7D%5C%2893%29+for+t%3D0)